# Load image on website after "10sec"

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I am writing an an website. I know for this problem I need JavaScript, unfortunately I can not do that yet.

I have a background Image Slideshow.
Every 6 seconds a new image appears.

My idea now is: Load the second image after 4sec, the third after 10sec, and so on.

Can you tell me how?
Thank you very much!

Comment: `setTimeout` method seems to be what you need => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: Hi Janneck, please detail your question, and provide some of the code you've already tried : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried so we may fix upon it?

Comment: Put the image slide show in an iframe which refreshes every 6 seconds and have the image url respond with a different image every time it is called

Comment: Plenty of slideshows out there that do it....

Comment: You should really get your timings in order: Title *"...after 10sec"* ... in question body *"...every 6 seconds"* ... further down *"...second image after 4 sec"*. Handing specs like this in a real world project wont make you friends.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know where to start I am going to give you a gentle nudge in the right direction. Keep in mind your framework, if you use any, might have wrappers around this, this is pure JS.

Also worth noting, there are different ways to handle this. Like for example put a listener when image changes then react to it, use canvas etc.

To **delay function calling** you can use `setTimeout` and pass a callback function to be called after number of milliseconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

In this example it will call anon function that calls alert after 3 seconds.

**If you wanna function to be repeatedly called every X** you need to use `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

This will do the same as 1st example but every 3 seconds indefinitely.

What you could do is to use only set interval but alter the timeout after the 1st image is loaded from 4000 to 6000 :)

If you name your timeouts and interval you can cancel them (especially important if you don't wanna interval to run indefinitely).

This should set you going if you don't know how to work with delays and intervals in js. 
For more you should post what you tried 1st.

Comment: Why the negative vote? Guy doesn't know where to start I pointed him in right direction per his request to use delay and interval. If he posts his attempt I will fix upon it, till then this is best I can come up with and it's too long for a comment.

Comment: Thank I will try it in the next days

Comment: @DanteTheSmith I agree, I don't understand why your answer has been downvoted. A helping community should not reject those kind answers that point fellow developers to a direction, despite the question not being that well expressed. I'm upvoting, and I hope Janneck finds his way into JavaScript!